# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-styles

I am getting this error in styles.xml:

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
> given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.

**In manifest:**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

**Android Sdk Manager:**

I am updated all the api 21 and extras.

[image]

[image]

**In Order and Export**:

[image]

**values-v21/styles.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">

        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_primary</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_secondary</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

**Console:**

```
E:\workspace\WelcomeToL\app\src\main\res\values-v21\styles.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.

E:\workspace\WelcomeToL\app\src\main\res\values-v21\styles.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
 
E:\workspace\WelcomeToL\app\src\main\res\values-v21\styles.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
 
E:\workspace\WelcomeToL\app\src\main\res\values-v21\styles.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.

E:\workspace\WelcomeToL\app\src\main\res\values-v21\styles.xml:10: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:navigationBarColor'.
```

I didn't know why this error still occurs.Anybody can help me with this.Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.

`Material.Light` theme require API level 21 for project. Set **Project Build Target** for project from `Properties->Android->Project Build Target` to `API 21`.

Comment: targetSdkVersion could be lower 21, but compileSdkVersion must be >= 21