# Setting targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion for bazel, android tensorflow

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-gradle-plugin, bazel

I need help in how to set the target and compile Sdk versions separately for bazel.

I want to run tensorflow on the phone following [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) tutorial. After editing WORKSPACE for bazel as follows:

```
android_sdk_repository(
    name = "androidsdk",
    api_level = 24,
    build_tools_version = "24.0.1",
    path = "/home/Android/Sdk",
)

android_ndk_repository(
    name="androidndk",
    path="/home/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle",
    api_level=21)
```

I get PARSE ERROR on the phone upon apk installing:

```
adb install -r bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/android/tensorflow_demo.apk
```

I have usb debugging and 3rd party apk installation enabled. The phone uses Android 4.4.4 so I changed WORKSPACE configuration to match it (tools and API installed by SDK manager properly) as:

```
android_sdk_repository(
    name = "androidsdk",
    api_level = 19,
    build_tools_version = "19.1.0",
    path = "/home/Android/Sdk",
)

android_ndk_repository(
    name="androidndk",
    path="/home/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle",
    api_level=21)
```

Upon building as:

```
bazel build //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo
```

I end up with few errors of that type:

```
Error at 5 : /tmp/android_resources_tmp7060220119759636814/merged_resources/values-v21/values.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
```

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812302/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name) answer, I should build for compile API version > 21 but at the same time target API version 19. It can be easily set for gradle. However I have not found any clue how to do that for [bazel](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/bazel-user-manual.html). Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target a lower Android API level, the file you want to edit is actually tensorflow/examples/android/AndroidManifest.xml. Leave the WORKSPACE file settings at the highest API level you have installed via your sdk (APIs can be installed with $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android).

You can lower the min API level to 19 in AndroidManifest.xml, but be aware you will encounter runtime errors on your phone running the demo unless you replace the demo code that interfaces with the camera2 api (which was added with API level 21) with analogous android.hardware.camera code.

Comment: thank you. Seems it would be reasonable to update the Android itself then to match camera2 api. Another question after looking into manifest file - how do the minSdkVersion 19 and targetSdkVersion 23 correlate with WORKSPACE sdk api_level 24? What effect has that api 24 then practically?

Comment: The default values in WORKSPACE are arbitrary -- they just happened to be what I had on my system at the time. As long as they are >= 23 the example should build fine.

Level 23 is required at compile-time for some code that checks permissions. This code is automatically skipped at runtime if the API level on the device is < 23.